# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in

Tags: magento2, xml, cron

`magento.cron log` return error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:449
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(116): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
#1 /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, 'xsi:type', NULL)
#2 /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(151): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml version="...')
#3 /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(132): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#4 /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor in /home/mall/domains/myweb.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 449
```

I check phpinfo
dom
DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.9.1
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
exif

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the php-dom and php-xml packages

> apt install php-dom php-xml

You likely need to restart PHP FPM or Apache for the changes to take effect

> systemctl restart php-fpm

or

> systemctl restart apache2